# webpack resolve alias for styles(stylus) as well in vue.js components

Tags: webpack, vue.js, stylus, webpack-style-loader

On a `vue.js`project in my `webpack.config.js`file i do have this:

```
///...,
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
    'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
    'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components')
  }
},
// ....
```

which is allowing me in any `Vue component` to use other components like this:

```
import 'component/path/to/MyComponent'
```

not having to wonder where i might in my components tree.

I wish ya have the same capacity with `styles`and particularly with `stylus``

Let say i do have
a `stylus file' in`src/assets/funcs.styl:

```
add(a)
  a + a
```

and a component in let say `src/components/a/very/long/path/MyComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="my-component">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'A title'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
@import "../../../../../../assets/funcs.styl"

h1
 margin add(30px)

</style>
```

I wish to be able to replace this line

```
@import "../../../../../../assets/funcs.styl"
```

by this

```
@import "assets/funcs"
```

using the `webpack` resolve and alias feature that works great for js files.
That would avoid hard to find bugs in big projects for stylus mixins and functions that i might need in deep components.

Is their a way to do so?
Does it have to be a feature request? on `webpack`? on `vue-style-loader`? on `stylus-loader`?

any precision would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Seb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

> @import '~assets/funcs';